# calling flex swf function from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, flash, invoke

I create a swf with flex. Than I embeded that swf into aspx page.But how can I access/invoke/call swf function from asp.net???

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly.  ASP.NET is a server side language; whereas Flex is a client side language.  ASP.NET code will generally generates HTML output.  And that output can include code to embed a SWF in the HTML page.

Flex can interact with the HTML Page using JavaScript and [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  JavaScript can call methods on the SWF using the same API.

Flex can call remote services written in ASPX using the [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html) tag for SOAP web Services, the [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html) tag for AMF services, or the [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html) tag for REST Web Services.  In most cases these operate int he "request/response" mechanism so that Flex must make a request to the server.

If you need the server to send data to your Flex App, you'll need a server that supports push notifications.  WebORB is one option that works with .NET.  LiveCycle and GraniteDS are alternate options.

Comment: Thank you for your post.I am working to understand WebORB but i cannot.

Comment: Thank you for your post. ExternalInterface is not using aspx  . It is so silly i cannot call flex function from aspx :(

Comment: @ugur_c Correct, ExternalInterface does not use ASPX. It's a way to call JavaScript from the Flash Player (and vice versa).  I'm not sure what you expect.  You question suggests an understanding of how ASPX pages work.  ASP.NET code generally executes on the server and generates HTML pages, which are delivered to the browser.  You can't call a JavaScript function in a web page from ASPX code either, can you?  I thought ASP.NET controls do a lot of masking of what is going on behind the scenes, but code either runs on the server w/ ASP.NET or on the client with JavaScript (or Flex).